# Google App Engine appcfg.py data_upload Authentication fail

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I am using appcfg.py to upload data to datastore from a csv file.
But every time I try, I am getting error:

```
[info    ] Authentication failed
```

even if i am using Admin id and password.
In my app.yaml file I am having:

```
handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin

- url: .*
  script: MainHandler.py
```

Can anybody please help me?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

That `app.yaml` file looks good to me, but are you sure it's been deployed to the server? The docs explicitly note that you need to update your app on the server before using `appcfg.py` to bulk upload data will work, so you might try the suggested command:

```
appcfg.py update <app-directory>
```

You might also look at [deleting your session cookies](http://blog.charlvn.com/2009/03/google-app-engine-appcfgpy-cookies.html), particularly if appcfg.py isn't asking you for your authentication each time -- it may have saved an incorrect password.

Hope some of this helps!

Comment: Thanks Adam,
  Yes i did upload application using the update command,At the time of uploading i used --no_cookies option and it i was asked for email and password and application being uploaded.

The when i am using same email and password to --upload_data it is again showing [info  ] Authentication failed.
this is going out of my mind.

Answer (score 2):

If your administrator is an Apps for Domains account (eg, @yourdomain.com), and your app uses Google Accounts authentication, you won't be able to authenticate as an admin on your app. You need to add a Google Accounts (eg, @google.com) account as an administrator, and use that to upload.

Comment: I'm having this problem with a gmail.com email address.

Comment: How do I add a normal Google account to my domain? Whenever I create a new user, the @yourdomain.com is added automatically.

Comment: You don't add it to your domain - you just add it as an administrator in the admin console of your App Engine app. Note that's different from the admin console for your domain!

Comment: Actually, I can update the application with appcfg and the new gmail user, but I still can't authenticate to get the bulkloader file. Should I open a new question?