# Email and password for uploading data to App Engine Development server using appcfg

Tags: google-app-engine

We are trying to download data from an app engine data store in our live environment and upload the same to the development server for reproducing an issue we found in a live environment.

Our application is in Java. But since we could not find a solution to download data, we downloaded the Python SDK and is using appcfg download_data and upload_data command for this purpose.

The download data worked fine and we were able to download data using the following command.

> appcfg.py download_data --url=http://.appspot.com/remote_api
>   --filename=mybackup.bak

It asked for email id and password, and we provided the email and password of an account who is an administrator in live application. But when we try the upload the data to local development server, the email id and password is becoming a roadblock.  The command we used is

> appcfg.py upload_data --num_threads=5
>   --url=http://localhost:8888/remote_api --filename= mybackup.bak

Once the script starts executing, it asks for email and password and we don’t know what we should provide.

Based on the various threads available online, we have done the following

1. Added the following to the app.yaml and ensured it comes at the top

   builtins:

   - remote_api: on
   - url: /api/remote
     script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
     login: admin
2. Tried using users as mentioned [here](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/devserver?hl=en#Using_Users)

But nothing worked so far.  We are getting the following message in console…

> [INFO    ] Logging to bulkloader-log-20150925.123803 [INFO    ]
>   Throttling transfers: [INFO    ] Bandwidth: 250000 bytes/second [INFO 
>   ] HTTP connections: 8/second [INFO    ] Entities
>   inserted/fetched/modified: 20/second[INFO    ] Batch Size: 10 Password
>   for a@a.com: Error 302: --- begin server output ---

What are we doing wrong? Any pointer will be highly appreciated. It’s been a day and no progress I could make so far…

Comment: Have a look here I hope it helps with your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2895397/google-app-engine-appcfg-py-data-upload-authentication-fail?rq=1

Comment: I finally could resolve this issue. The problem had nothing to do with appcfg.py. We were using Spring security and the /remote_api didn't had the permissions. Once I added the following line                            <intercept-url pattern="/remote_api" access="permitAll" /> in to web.xml, it started working

Comment: it is acceptable to answer and accept the answer to your own question if you think it'll be handy in the future to someone else.